# Preservation of left nullspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

For some matrix A, and some matrix A* obtained from a series of elementary row operations on A, are the left nullspaces of A and A* equal?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no.  However, if we were to perform "elementary column operations" to get $A^*$, then this would be the case.

We can check that this is indeed the case with a simple example: take $A$ to be
$$
A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
You can verify that $x A = 0$ exactly when $x = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & t\end{bmatrix}$ for some $t$.  Now, consider
$$
A^* = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
What is the left-nullspace of $A^*$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider 
$$
A =  
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
and
$$
A' =  
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Then look at $v$
$$
v = (0 ~~ 1 ~~0)$$

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider $A:=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}$ and add the first row to the second: $A^*:=\pmatrix{1&0\\1&0}$, then the left null space of $A$ is the line of $(0,1)$, but that of $A^*$ is generated by $(1,-1)$.